# excluding first and last lines from sed /START/,/END/

Tags: unix, scripting, sed, text-manipulation

Consider the input:

```
=sec1=
some-line
some-other-line

foo
bar=baz

=sec2=
c=baz
```

If I wish to process only =sec1= I can for example comment out the section by:

```
sed -e '/=sec1=/,/=[a-z]*=/s:^:#:' < input
```

... well, almost.

This will comment the lines *including* "=sec1=" and "=sec2=" lines, and the result will be something like:

```
#=sec1=
#some-line
#some-other-line
#
#foo
#bar=baz
#
#=sec2=
c=baz
```

My question is: **What is the easiest way to exclude the start and end lines from a /START/,/END/ range in sed**?

I know that for many cases refinement of the "s:::" claws can give solution in this specific case, but I am after the generic solution here.

In "[Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29)" Bruce Barnett writes: "I will show you later how to restrict a command up to, but not including the line containing the specified pattern.", but I was not able to find where he actually show this.

In the "[USEFUL ONE-LINE SCRIPTS FOR SED](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)" Compiled by Eric Pement, I could find only the inclusive example:

```
# print section of file between two regular expressions (inclusive)
sed -n '/Iowa/,/Montana/p'             # case sensitive
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -e '/=sec1=/,/=sec2=/ { /=sec1=/b; /=sec2=/b; s/^/#/ }' < input
```

This matches between sec1 and sec2 inclusively and then just skips the first and last line with the `b` command.  This leaves the desired lines between sec1 and sec2 (exclusive), and the `s` command adds the comment sign.

Unfortunately, you do need to repeat the regexps for matching the delimiters.  As far as I know there's no better way to do this.  At least you can keep the regexps clean, even though they're used twice.

This is adapted from the [SED FAQ: How do I address all the lines between RE1 and RE2, excluding the lines themselves?](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24)

Comment: For folks on macOS with BSD sed you need to use actual newlines instead of semicolons. For more details check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15470635/2909897)

Comment: not sure about other versions, but with GNU sed, this could be easily done using `'/=sec1=/,/=sec2=/ { //! s/^/#/ }'` ... from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses) `empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match`

Comment: @Sundeep Given that this is the most concise expression, why not post it as answer?

Answer (score 14):

If you're not interested in lines outside of the range, but just want the non-inclusive variant of the Iowa/Montana example from the question (which is what brought me here), you can write the "except for the first and last matching lines" clause easily enough with a second sed:

`sed -n '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/p' < input | sed '1d;$d'`

Personally, I find this slightly clearer (albeit slower on large files) than the equivalent

`sed -n '1,/PATTERN1/d;/PATTERN2/q;p' < input`

Comment: nice. also, the second version doesn't blow up php because of that pesky $.

Comment: I have a hunch, they're not equivalent, should there be more than one of those ranges in the stream/file.

Answer (score 7):

Another way would be

```
sed '/begin/,/end/ {
       /begin/n
       /end/ !p
     }'
```

`/begin/n` -> skip over the line that has the "begin" pattern
`/end/ !p` -> print all lines that don't have the "end" pattern

Taken from Bruce Barnett's sed tutorial http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-35a

Answer (score 2):

you could also use awk

```
awk '/sec1/{f=1;print;next}f && !/sec2/{ $0="#"$0}/sec2/{f=0}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used:

```
sed '/begin/,/end/{/begin\|end/!p}'
```

This will search all the lines between the patterns, then print everything not containing the patterns

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to repeat any regular expression(s) to make this work.

```bash
$ sed -e '/^=sec1=$/{:0;n;/^=\w*=$/!{s/^/#/;b0}}' <<EOF
=sec1=
some-line
some-other-line

foo
bar=baz

=sec2=
c=baz
EOF
```

The output will be:

```
=sec1=
#some-line
#some-other-line
#
#foo
#bar=baz
#
=sec2=
c=baz
```

Taking apart the sed script, we have:

1. `/^=sec1=$/` a regular expression address matching the opening section marker
2. `{:0;n;/^=\w*=$/!{s/^/#/;b0}}` a command block, as follows:

   1. `:0` a label to return to later
   2. `n` print the current line, and read the next line
   3. `/^=\w*=$/!` a regular expression address matching any line that isn't a section marker
   4. `{s/^/#/;b0}` a command block, as follows:

      1. `s/^/#/` prepend a `#` to the line
      2. `b0` branch to label `0`

The inner loop between `:0` and `b0` continues looping until it encounters any line that is a section marker (or the end of the file).