# Generic command to search for a part of a text file and print it (using awk or sed)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Which command should I use to print a part of  text files knowing where this part starts and finishes?

For example:

```
columnA columnB columnC
baba     bobo    bibi
caca     coco    cici  
.         .      .
.         .      .
zaza    zeze     zizi
EndA    EndB    EndC
```

In all my files I have exactly the same text for columnA(columnB ...) and EndA(EndB ...), what I want to do is to print what is in between them, i.e., baba(bobo ...) which is different for each file.

I was doing that using, grep | cut | tail, but then I have to write ( and find) new patterns  each time I have a new file as the number of lines of each of them are different. I suppose there is a much more smarter ( and generic) way to do that using awk or sed.

Comment: IIUC, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187354/excluding-first-and-last-lines-from-sed-start-end) might be an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking print all but the first and last lines you could do

```
sed '1d; $d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

and next to the sed solution, awk can be used as wel:

```
BEGIN {
  output=0;
}

$1 ~ /columnA/ || $1 ~ /endA/ {
  output=!output;
  next;
}

{ if(start_output) print $0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

sed has ranges:

```
 sed -ne '/^columnA/,/^EndA/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use head and tail

```
head -n-1 temp.txt | tail -n +2
```

Output

```
baba     bobo    bibi
caca     coco    cici
.         .      .
.         .      .
zaza    zeze     zizi
```