# Replace section of text file using sed/awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace the text in a file between # begin and # end as follows:

```
# begin

# [block]
# param1=""
# param2=""

# end
```

to read as:

```
# begin

[block]
param1="value1"
param2="value2"

# end
```

Basically, I'm uncommenting the [block] line as well as the param values that fall under it.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution that avoids unneeded loops, using Mac OS X's BSD sed<sup>1</sup>:

```sed
/# begin/,/# end/ {    # Search only within this range of text.
  //!s/^# //           # Excluding range borders, delete /^# / from each line.
}
```

Testing:

```
▶ cat > FILE <<EOF
aaa
bbb
# begin

# [block]
# param1=""
# param2=""

# end
ccc
ddd
EOF
```

```
▶ sed -i '' '/# begin/,/# end/{//!s/^# //;}' FILE
```

```
▶ cat FILE
aaa
bbb
# begin

[block]
param1=""
param2=""

# end
ccc
ddd
```

Further explanation:

- Note that the empty regular expression `//` repeats the last regular expression match. Thus, `//!` negates that. And `/PAT1/,/PAT2/{ //! X }` has the effect of excluding both `/PAT1/` and `/PAT2/` for `X`.

---

<sup>1</sup> And also tested using GNU sed.

Answer (score 2):

by sed:

```
sed '/^# begin/,/^# end/{/^# \(begin\|end\)/b a;s/^# *//; :a}' your_file > new_file
```

it's slightly complicated:

```
/^# begin/,/^# end/         # match from begin to end
{
    /^# \(begin\|end\)/b a; # if it's begin or end, jump to label a
    s/^# *//;               # delete all sharps
     :a                     # label a locates at the end
}
```

demo:

```
$ cat f
# begin

# [block]
# param1=""
# param2=""

# end

$ sed '/^# begin/,/^# end/{/^# \(begin\|end\)/b a;s/^# *//; :a}' f
# begin

[block]
param1=""
param2=""

# end
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks! Now what if "# begin" and "# end" didn't always exist and the # [block] and param section existed somewhere in the middle...how would I be able to replace it still?

Comment: it will replace everything after the first discovery of begin and till the first discovery of end.

Comment: Gotcha...is there I way I can make it uncomment the lines beginning at `# [block]` and ending at the first instance of a carriage return...disregarding the `# begin` and `# end` lines?

Comment: @AndrewWeiss don't get it. sed defaultly parses file line by line which means your file should be multi-lined. maybe you can update you question with another example.

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS X: `sed: 1: "/^# begin/,/^# end/{/^# ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: @Keith a quick search indicates the sed shipped with mac is not working the same as gnu sed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467616/sed-gives-me-unexpected-eof-pending-s-error-and-i-have-no-idea-why

Comment: MacOS `sed` dislikes semicolons after labels, I think you need to use a literal newline instead of a semicolon.