# Replace LaTeX with $ and multi-line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, latex

I want to use sed to replace something like `$some latex$` or

```
$$
some latex
$$
```

with `{% math %}some latex {% endmath %}` or

```
{% math %}
some latex
{% endmath %}
```

I try sed to solve this problem but a command like

```
sed -e 's/\$\([^\$]\{1,\}\)\$/{% math %}\1{% endmath %}/g' filename
```

doesn't work for `$some latex$` and I don't know how to deal with multi-line. How can I do this?

Comment: In general, `sed` is not the right tool for this. Something as simple `$ \$ $` would break any tool that does not actually understand LaTeX syntax.

Comment: It is not quite clear if `$some latex$` is on a line on its own (probably not) - a real example of what your input looks like would go a long way. And is `$$` always on a separate line? And there are no `\[ \]` anywhere to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with sed :

```
sed -e ' /\$\$/{s/\$\$/{% math %}/;:a;N;/\$\$/!ba;s/\$\$/{% endmath %}/};s/^\(\$\)\(.*\)\(\$\)$/{% math %}\2{% endmath %}/' sourcefile
```

Multiline is preserved.

**Update :**

It seems there is a BSD (OS X?) [sed issue with semi colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467616/sed-gives-me-unexpected-eof-pending-s-error-and-i-have-no-idea-why).

It should work replacing it with new lines :

```
sed -e '
  /\$\$/ {
    s/\$\$/{% math %}/
      :a
      N
      /\$\$/!ba
      s/\$\$/{% endmath %}/;}
      s/^\(\$\)\(.*\)\(\$\)$/{% math %}\2{% endmath %}/
' sourcefile
```

I also updated the last `s` command to match lines like `$ \$ $` mentioned in you comments.

Comment: There is some mistake when running it.`sed: 1: " /\$\$/ { s/\$\$/{% mat ...": whitespace after label
sed: 1: " /\$\$/ { s/\$\$/{% mat ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/24276470#24276470) is a great overview of GNU/BSD sed differences and how to overcome them.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the link. There is much more differences than i imagined. I added a `-e` to sed. Hope it will do the trick.

Comment: I actually don't think it will, but newlines should go a long way - and "enter code here" is an editing artefact, right?

Comment: "The most portable approach is to use POSIX features only". I tried with the --posix GNU option and it works for me.

Comment: I get the following message when trying the second approach on Mac `": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: You're right @JaneWayne. A missing `;`. I updated the multiline command.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you are facing here is **capturing newline or whitespace**, which is solved by following regex.

**Regex:** `(?:\$*)(\s*)some latex(\s*)(?:\$*)`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search.

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\$*)(\s*)` captures the whitespace or newline after leading `$` or `$$`
- `(\s*)(?:\$*)` captures the whitespace or newline before trailing `$` or `$$`

**Replacement to do:** `{% math %}\1some latex\2{% endmath %}`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB1xK3/1)**</kbd>

Comment: There may some misunderstanding. What's inside $ is latex code like P_{ij}, and is not the string "some latex". For example, I would like to replace $ in `$P\left\{X_n=j|X_{n-1}=i\right\}=P_{ij}$`

Comment: This regex wouldn't work for sed anyway: it doesn't understand non-capturing groups and `\s`.

Comment: @modkzs: You didn't clarified that in the question above. We can replace `some latex` with `.*` to match everything in between `$`. And it would do the same job.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I tried to provide a help from regex point of view. This might not be a **complete** solution but will definitely help in developing it.