# How do I replace LaTex $ delimiters using a command line tool like perl or sed?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, jupyter-notebook

I have a bunch of Jupyter Notebooks with equations written in LaTex. I know that I can convert the notebook to HTML as follows.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --template basic test.ipynb test.html
```

However, the LaTex markup are preserved. For example, if I have `$y = w'x$`, then that still shows up in the output HTML. I want to get this generated HTML into WordPress (basically, copy/paste), but [WordPress](https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/) delimits LaTex like this `$latex y = w'x$`.

How can I use `perl` or `sed` (or anything else) to convert `$y = w'x` to `$latex y = w'x$`?

I know I can just write a program to do it, but I think that's an overkill because I am sure these available command line tools can do it to. Additionally, any tool that is available on both Windows and Mac/Linux would be a bonus, since I work on both environment types, and do not want to have to resort to a *nix like environment to do this conversion (though, Windows does have Windows Linux Subsystem now, so I guess that might be ok if it's just a Linux tool).

I tried to modify this `sed` expression from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815988/replace-latex-with-and-multi-line) (on Mac), but it did not work.

```
sed -e ' /\$\$/{s/\$\$/{\$latex }/;:a;N;/\$\$/!ba;s/\$\$/{\$}/};s/^\(\$\)\(.*\)\(\$\)$/{\$latex }\2{\$}/' test.html
```

> unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/\$\([^$]*\)\$/$\\latex \1$/g'
```

**INPUT:**

```
$ echo -e "abc \$y = w'x$ toto\n123 \$u = v'w$ xyz"
abc $y = w'x$ toto
123 $u = v'w$ xyz
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
echo -e "abc \$y = w'x$ toto\n123 \$u = v'w$ xyz" | sed -e 's/\$\([^$]*\)\$/$\\latex \1$/g'
abc $\latex y = w'x$ toto
123 $\latex u = v'w$ xyz
```

**Explanations:**

You use `sed` in find and replace mode and it will replace everything between two `$` characters via  this regex: `\$\([^$]*\)\$` by what is already here (backreference) and add `\latex` at the beginning.

Last but not least, the following `sed -e 's/\$\([^$]*\)\$/$latex \1$/g'` sed command does the `$latex` replacement without the `\`

Comment: Cool. That worked! Could you modify it to remove the output to `$\latex` and just `$latex` since the latter is compliant with WordPress and so other users won't be confused? I'll accept this answer as it completely works (minus the output of `$\latex` part. I've already modified it on my test here and it works; just need the edit in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the whole format of your file might be.  If I take your example at face value and assume that the first `$` on any line is in column 1 then

```
sed -e's/^\$/$\\latex /'
```

works for me.  But if the string to convert is *anywhere* in the file then things get harder.

Comment: That does not seem to work; I don't observe any of the delimiters being swapped out. And yes, there will be many equations delimited by `$` pairs throughout the generated HTML. Again, to be clear, I create a Juypter Notebook `ipynb` file (which is `JSON`), and then use the `juypter nbconvert` tool to create a `HTML` file. The whole format that I would be operating against is a HTML file.

Comment: Well, I'm not that familiar with Juypter Notebook.  Do all equations start with `$`?  Rather you might try `sed -e's/\$/$\\latex /'`.