# AWS EC2 : Safe way to get host public key

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

When I connect to the AWS EC2 instance using ssh for the first time, I got an error like below because the host key is not stored in ssh known_hosts file.

> The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x' can't be
>   established. ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   xx:yy:.... Are you sure you want
>   to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Now, I'm automating ssh. I often just add StrictHostKeyChecking option to ssh command to avoid this message.
But, I feel that is not very safe way and possibly cause Man in the middle attack.
Is there any (or good) way to get host key safely on AWS EC2?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: IMO question is about programming because it is about automation.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way is to parse the console output.

```
#get the console output of the instance
aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id <instance id> |\
#use jq to get the Output field
jq .Output -r |\
#use sed to find the interesting bits
sed -n -e '1,/-----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----/d; /-----END SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----/q; p'
```

Caveats, which might not matter depending on your application:

- `aws` output is JSON, so we need to parse it
- [output requires some sed massage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218716/856769)
- output may not be the same depending on the AMI?